# Play Single Youtube video with Google Hangout API and Share with other Participants

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

I want to create a Google Hangout App that will take a youtube video id through the Hangout Button ( StartData) and then share and watch video with other Hangout participants.

Workflow:

1) click on Google hangout button
2) youtube video id gets sent with StartData
3) Retrieve and save StartData in gapi.hangout.data Shared State so other google hangout participants retrieve the same video.
4) Add youtube event listener for play/pause in the shared state so other participants watch a youtube video together.

Here is my XML file:

**Basic Top of the Google Hangout app**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Module>
<!-- Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
 * use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
 * the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0  *    
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
 * License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
 * the License
-->
<ModulePrefs title="Fitcasts">
<Require feature="rpc" />
<Require feature="views" />
<Require feature="locked-domain" />
</ModulePrefs>
```

**Simple Play/ Pause Button**

```
<Content type="html"><![CDATA[     
    <script src="//talkgadget.google.com/hangouts/api/hangout.js?v=1.0"></script>

<style type="text/css">
</style>

<h2>Pause / Play Buttons for YouTube Videos</h2>

# play pause button for youtube
<a src="#" class="button" id="play-button">Play
  </a>
  <a src="#" class="button" id="pause-button">Pause
  </a>
```

**iframe for just random video at first but I want it to be a specific video get put into a
// StartData with google hangout button**

```
<iframe id="video" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/FKWwdQu6_ok?enablejsapi=1&html5=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**Javascript portion of it**

```
<script> 

  // https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference     
  function HangoutDemo() {  
    console.log("Starting..."); 
    gapi.hangout.onApiReady.add(this.onApiReady.bind(this));  
  } 

  HangoutDemo.prototype.onApiReady = function (event) { 
    if (event.isApiReady === true) {  
      console.log("API Ready");   
      document.getElementById("play-button").onclick =  
        this.buttonClick.bind(this);  
      gapi.hangout.data.onStateChanged.add( // add callback for event
        this.buttonClick.bind(this)  
      );  
      this.buttonClick();  
    } 
  };  


  HangoutDemo.prototype.buttonClick = function () { 
    // global variable for the player
var player;

// this function gets called when API is ready to use
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  // create the global player from the specific iframe (#video)
  player = new YT.Player('video', {
    events: {
      // call this function when player is ready to use
      'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {

  // bind events
  var playButton = document.getElementById("play-button");
  playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    player.playVideo();
  });

  var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pause-button");
  pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    player.pauseVideo();
  });

}

// Inject YouTube API script
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  };  

  var hangoutDemo = new HangoutDemo();  
</script>
]]>
</Content>
</Module>﻿
```

Comment: This is a ton of code. Reduce your question down to exactly what is going wrong, rather than letting us create your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to be able to set and monitor the shared hangout state and act accordingly.

So the player event listeners may look something like this:

```
playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  gapi.hangout.data.setValue('playState','play');
  player.playVideo();
});

pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  gapi.hangout.data.setValue('playState','pause');
  player.pauseVideo();
});
```

You will also need to register event handlers that will listen for the state change events and act accordingly. Something like this might work:

```
gapi.hangout.data.onStateChanged.add(function(stateChange){
  switch( stateChange.state.playState ){
    case 'play':
      player.playVideo();
      break;
    case 'pause':
      player.pauseVideo();
      break;
  }
});
```

For more information, see:

- https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.data#gapi.hangout.data.setValue
- https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.data#gapi.hangout.data.onStateChanged
- https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.data#gapi.hangout.data.StateChangedEvent

Comment: I got it to work. One comment is that I changed gapi.hangout.value.setValue to gapi.hangout.data.setValue. I am sure it was just a typo. Thank you for your help